# How to move multiple files with whitespace on linux

Tags: linux, xargs, mv

Hello I'm newbie in linux, what I'm going to ask is about moving file on linux using awk and xargs, apologies if I'm reposting..

I have apprx 1000-5000 files like this:

-rw-rw-r--  1 wm files   77641 Mar  3 11:20 sendOrder.ZBAM.0005167032-20130503 11:20:35.txt

-rw-rw-r--  1 wm files   77647 Apr  3 11:20 sendOrder.ZBAM.0005167033-20130503 11:20:36.txt

-rw-rw-r--  1 wm files   77655 May  3 11:20 sendOrder.ZBAM.0005167034-20130503 11:20:37.txt

-rw-rw-r--  1 wm files   77661 May  3 11:20 sendOrder.ZBAM.0005167035-20130503 11:20:38.txt

-rw-rw-r--  1 wm files   77556 May  3 11:20 sendOrder.ZBAM.0005167036-20130503 11:20:39.txt

-rw-rw-r--  1 wm files   77549 May  3 11:20 sendOrder.ZBAM.0005167037-20130503 11:20:40.txt

-rw-rw-r--  1 wm files   77549 Jun  3 11:20 sendOrder.ZBAM.0005167038-20130503 11:20:41.txt

-rw-rw-r--  1 wm files   77543 Jun  3 11:20 sendOrder.ZBAM.0005167039-20130503 11:20:42.txt

As you can see the filename contains whitespace at -20130503 11:20:42.txt, so I'm using:
**STEP 1**

```
ls -la|grep -e "May"|awk "{print $9, $10}" > some.files
```

*In step 1 I've already got the list file i want to move by month of "May" inside some.files*
**STEP 2**

```
xargs -0 some.files mv -t dir/newdir/
```

Step 2 won't work.. What am I supposed to do? I'm using Linux CentOS 5.3

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about using Unix commands

Comment: 1. Don't parse `ls`. 2. Use `find` to list the files and then either pipe output to `xargs` or use the `-exec` option. 3. Improve your search skills; you'll be able to find numerous examples for similar problems.

Comment: Can I list the file using find? Because I need the list of file regarding month which I'm selected, it's the reason i use awk.

Comment: See `man find`.  Try to look at some questions on the right (those listed `Related`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's probably 400 ways to do this.. using find is likely the more efficient way, but:

You can use a for loop:

```
for i in `ls`; do mv $i dir/newdir/; done
```

Or a while loop with the file you created in your step 1:

```
ls -la|grep -e "May"|awk "{print $9, $10}" > some.files; cat some.files | while read mFILE; do mv $mFILE dir/newdir; done
```

Or with find (where +30 is greater than X days):

```
find ./ -mtime +30 -exec mv dir/newdir {} \;
```

OR, if you want to use awk and xargs:

```
ls -la|grep -e "May"|awk "{print $9, $10}" | xargs mv dir/newdir/
```

Comment: beware that the `find` option will find files in subfolders also! You can add `-maxdepth 1` to prevent this.

Answer (score 0):

With GNU Parallel you can do:

```
 ls | parallel -X mv {} dir/newdir/
```

10 seconds installation:

```
wget -O - pi.dk/3 | sh
```

Learn more: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1